# Set Session Ajax Post

Tags: php, ajax, post

anyway for set session when remote login with ajax .

this is my code

```
var result = null;
var scriptUrl = "http://www.site.com/login.bs";

   $.ajax({ 
     url: scriptUrl,
     type: 'post',
     data: ({txtTitle : 'tt1', txtText : 'tt2'}),
     dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error"); 
        } 
     });
```

in target page when login session[user] set . but when i refresh page alert error .

target code

```
if($_POST[txtTitle]=='tt1' && $_POST[txtText]=='tt2') 
{
     $_SESSION[user]='ok';
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION[user]` -- this should have quotes around the `user`, so it should look like this: `$_SESSION['user']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the backend, the javascript is expecting some sort of a json response. `dataType: 'json'`

Try:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array());
```